# How to get class type for GenericTypes in java

Tags: java, scala, class, generics, types

I have below code in scala

```
classOf[KafkaLog[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]]]
```

I want to implement the same in Java, but this throws NPE

```
   getClass {
     Class<KafkaLog<byte[], byte[]>> clazzz = null;
     return clazzz;
    }
```

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, let alone throw any exception.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent code in Java is `KafkaLog.class`. Yes, just this. If you really need a value of type `Class<KafkaLog<byte[], byte[]>>` you should rethink your design (and if you can't, IIRC you have to do a double cast: `(Class<KafkaLog<byte[], byte[]>>) (Class<?>) KafkaLog.class`).